# POST request error, Flask-Restless issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask-restless

I'm facing a very weird problem with a post request. I'm using Flask-Restless to create an API with GET and POST methods.

In my view a have a button and `onclick i would like to send a POST request.

My code:

```
var Insert = function(inputdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/user',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'description':'test'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success: ' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="Insert()">Input</button>
```

When i'm trying to click the button i'm getting an error and specially :

`POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user 400 (BAD REQUEST)`

a response

`{"message": "Unable to decode data"}`

If i try to send POST request through postman Chrome extension **everything works fine**.

Did i miss something?

Comment: @RobertMoskal thanks for your comment. It needs JSON.stringify to fix key,value pair into raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

`data: JSON.stringify({ 'description' : 'test'}),`

The JSON.stringify is required.